# Unable to use whereHas in Laravel Algolia Scout

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I am working on a Laravel project. I am using Scout based on Algolia. Now, I cannot apply whereHas to the search.

I have a model called Place which has many to many relationships with Category with the following code.

```
class Place extends Model
{
    use Searchable, Localizable;

    protected $with = [
        'images',
        'phones',
        'emails',
        'categories'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'is_featured' => 'boolean'
    ];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'place_category');
    }

    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return "places_index";
    }

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $record = $this->toArray();
        $record['_geoloc'] = [
            'lat' => $record['latitude'],
            'lng' => $record['longitude'],
        ];
        unset($record['created_at'], $record['updated_at'], $record['latitude'], $record['longitude']);

        return $record;
    }
}
```

As you can see it will be indexed on Algolia.

I am searching based on geolocation and keyword using the following code.

```
Place::search($keyword, function ($algolia, $query, $options) use ($latitude, $longitude) {
            $location = [
                'aroundLatLng' => $latitude . ',' . $longitude,
                'aroundRadius' => config('scout.algolia.search_radius'),
            ];
            $options = array_merge($options, $location);

            return $algolia->search($query, $options);
        });
```

The code is working fine until I also tried to filter by category. I changed my code to something like this.

```
$query = Place::search($keyword, function ($algolia, $query, $options) use ($latitude, $longitude) {
                $location = [
                    'aroundLatLng' => $latitude . ',' . $longitude,
                    'aroundRadius' => config('scout.algolia.search_radius'),
                ];
                $options = array_merge($options, $location);
    
                return $algolia->search($query, $options);
            });

        if ($category) {
            $query = $query->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('categories.id', $category);
            });
        }
```

As you can see now, I am now filtering by categories too using whereHas. When I run the code, I got the following error.

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Laravel\Scout\Builder::whereHas does not exist.
```

Literally, I cannot use whereHas with Algolia search. How can I fix it? Also, I am thinking of indexing the categories and filter the records on the Algolia side.But I am going to be filtering by id. How can I customise the query for it?

Comment: whats your laravel version?

Comment: Hi, I am using Laravel version, 6.18.35.